# reading multiple data value from the serial port with c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am sending multiple data to C#  using the serial port. I want to convert the `string[]` into integers and use them in an `if statement`:

```
string[] c = serialPort1.ReadExisting().Split(',');
int b = Int32.Parse(c[0]);
int d = Int32.Parse(c[1]);
```

But I am getting an error:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format'

Comment: and what did the strings in `c[0]` and `c[1]` look like? They are obviously not parseable by `Int32.Parse` (note that even leading/trailing whitespaces can lead to that exception)

Comment: Have you checked what the Input string is?

Comment: How do you send the data to the serial port - what format is it in? Do you wait long enough for all the data to be received?

Comment: if l use this code textBox1.Text = c[0]; its printing integer value to the textbox...now if l want to use an if statement with the data its not working

Comment: what do you suggest l use Mr vogt l tried using Convert.toint16 and l am still getting the same error

Comment: It would help a great deal if you showed use examples of the data you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from what you have given us it looks like the data that you are attempting to parse is in to incorrect format. As it appears that this can happen it would probably be best to use a try parse which will prevent system crashes in the event that this happens again.

Use the **try parse** as follows just for the first int but should be simple enough to add to the other int:

```
if (c.Length > 1) {
    int b;
    int d;


    bool result = Int32.TryParse(c[0], out b);
    bool result1 = Int32.TryParse(c[1], out d);
    if (result && result1) {
        if (b < 200) {
        //Do Something!!!
        }
    } else {
        //Do Whatever you wanted to do when the data was incorrect
        Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                                   value == null ? "<null>" : value);
    }
} else {
   //Input from socket comms was not of the correct input!!!
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much....... the problem is l want to compare the result with an if statement eg if (result<200) do this its not working properly because its a bool what can l do

Comment: if result is true, then the value of b is what you want in your if statement.

Comment: ok thank you but if l repeat the same method to get the other input variable (c[1]) l am getting this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @BarneyTwist the result variable is just to make sure that there is a number to comapre you would still compare to b.

So to do your comparrision you would do if(b<200).

Comment: @BarneyTwist this means that your array doens't have 2 entries. See edit for a full safe version of you you are trying to do.

Comment: @BarneyTwist: I have repeatedly said - please show your input string - we can only guess what is or isn't happening without that. It now seems you only have one string - so the split did not work.

Comment: I would have changed the start of the code to something like _"string InputString = serialPort1.ReadExisting(); string[] c = InputString.Split(',');"_ for ease of seeing what data has been received. Also, if it is an issue with leading/trailing spaces then _"bool result = Int32.TryParse(c[0].Trim(), out b);"_

Comment: l am getting the inputs from 2 trct5000 sensors connected to an arduino

Comment: i cant post the arduino code here because this is a c# platforms thats the problem

Comment: @BarneyTwist Can I ask why you think the data from 2 separate devices will come into one serial stream, comma separated?? Have you got a library or something sorting that out or something?